# Set up django-celery-email for local dev

Tags: django, celery, django-allauth, pipenv

It seems the best way to send emails from the django-allauth app asynchronously is to simply install django-celery-email.  But the packages warns that

> This version requires the following versions:Python 2.7 and Python3.5, Django 1.11, 2.1, and 2.2 Celery 4.0

I've only been using python for several months and never encountered a situation where two python version are needed on a project.  And I'm using the official recommendation of pipenv for local development.  A quick google shows that it isn't possible to have two python interpreters installed in the virtual environment.  Since the plugin seems so popular I wondered how others were setting it up?  Apologies if I've missed something major that explains this.

A bonus answer would also take into account that I am using docker and the docker image will install the python packages like this.

`RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is just inaccurate description in the [project docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-email/), so you need either python 2.7 or python >=3.5 to be installed

Answer (score 0):

In the end I didn't use django-celery-email.  It's easy to send the emails generated by the django-allauth app without this package.

I used these resources -

https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail/issues/79

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#defining-a-custom-email-backend

Basically you do this to get it working.

In settings.py define a CustomEmailBackend -

`EMAIL_BACKEND = "users.backends.CustomEmailBackend"`

In a backend.py file define the backend -

```
from django.core.mail.backends.base import BaseEmailBackend
from .tasks import async_send_messages

class CustomEmailBackend(BaseEmailBackend):
    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        async_send_messages.delay(email_messages)
        return len(email_messages)
```

And this is the task -

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection

from abstract_base_user.celery import app

@app.task(rety_backoff=True, serializer="pickle")
def async_send_messages(email_messages):
    conn = get_connection(backend='anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend')
    conn.send_messages(email_messages)
```

The celery django app should be set up in the standard way as defined at https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

And the celery settings in the settings.py need include the pickle content type -

`CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'pickle']`

Obviously you need to include your anytime settings and broker settings too.  But this should be enough to get anybody started.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make this better. The serializing with pickle was not acceptable imo.

```py
class AsyncSmtpEmailBackend(SmtpEmailBackend):
    
    def serialize_message(self, email_message):
        if not email_message.recipients():
            return False
        encoding = email_message.encoding or settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
        from_email = sanitize_address(email_message.from_email, encoding)
        recipients = [
            sanitize_address(addr, encoding) for addr in email_message.recipients()
        ]
        msg = email_message.message()
        msg_data = msg.as_bytes(linesep="\r\n")
        charset = (
            msg.get_charset().get_output_charset() if msg.get_charset() else "utf-8"
        )
        msg_data = msg_data.decode(charset)
        serialized_data = {
            "from_email": from_email,
            "recipients": recipients,
            "message": msg_data,
        }
        return json.dumps(serialized_data)


    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        msgs = [self.serialize_message(msg) for msg in email_messages]
        async_send_messages_with_smtp.delay(msgs)
        return len(email_messages)
    

    def _send(self, email_message):
        email_message = json.loads(email_message)
        from_email = email_message['from_email']
        recipients = email_message['recipients']
        message = email_message['message']
        try:
            self.connection.sendmail(
                from_email, recipients, message
            )
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            if not self.fail_silently:
                raise
            return False
        return True
```

and in `tasks.py`

```py
@shared_task()
def async_send_messages_with_smtp(email_messages):
    conn = get_connection(backend=settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
    if not email_messages:
        return 0
    with conn._lock:
        new_conn_created = conn.open()
        if not conn.connection or new_conn_created is None:
            # We failed silently on open().
            # Trying to send would be pointless.
            return 0
        num_sent = 0
        for message in email_messages:
            sent = conn._send(message)
            if sent:
                num_sent += 1
        if new_conn_created:
            conn.close()
    return num_sent
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).